# Screen scraping/accessing data from another app an android/iphone app

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, packet-capture

I have zero experience with apps and smartphone development. I would like to know if it's possible to screen scrape or otherwise access data coming from apps on smartphone?

Like If Im using some app that displays a list of train timetables or sporting fitxures, is it possible to access this data from another app on the phone? Even if it means capturing packets being sent to/from the phone. Any know what my options are when it comes to capturing data being displayed/used by another app on a smartphone?

Comment: Why the downvote...this kind of thing can be done on a pc - pcap for packets, selenium to control web browsers, various debuggers...why am i getting downvoted for asking if it can be done on a smartphone?

Answer (score 3):

Basically no. This would represent a huge security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Point your phone proxy to a PC will proxy facility.
2. Forward all packet to an app and push those packet into file. (PCAP format perhaps, something like the TCPDUMP command in Ubuntu.
3. Then you can read the packet content.

You will have to write this App yourself. (I am not sure if there is such App around)